# Multi Label classification with Sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression, multilabel-classification

I have tried using the OneVsRest with Logistic Regression from Sklearn, but it gives empty labels for some samples (i.e. doesn't predict any out), even though I do not have any unlabelled training data.

Any idea what might be causing this or how to fix this?

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(multi_class='ovr',max_iter=1000,solver='lbfgs'))
clf.fit(X,Y)
self.classifier=clf


self.classifier.predict(test_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are performing MultiLabel classification, according to the `OneVsRestClassifier` the targets need to be **"a sequence of sequences of labels"**.

Moreover, depending on how you encode this labels you may get the following warning: "DeprecationWarning: Direct support for sequence of sequences multilabel representation will be unavailable from version 0.17. Use sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer to convert to a label indicator representation."

So, neat way to encode your labels:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
mlb = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()
Y = mlb.fit_transform([(1, 2), (1,2), (1,2),(4,)]) 
# this means sample one belongs to classes {1,2} and so on. 
# Take into account the format if only one class is needed, (4,) not (4)
```

so Y turns out to be:

```
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing to train the data the format is (4,) for single labels. However this doesn't help with the some of the test data being labelled as None.

Comment: okay, is there any way you could give us an example of one of this samples that ends up in a `None` prediction? Maybe the algorithm itself or its implementation permits indetermination in sklearn and returns `None`. Try to give us an example, in the meanwhile I'll check some theory.

Comment: You could also check the `predict_proba(X)` method instead of `predict` and see if it returns `None` as well

Comment: I am not sure how to give an example here, because the one's that have predicted labels are similar to the ones without the predicted labels. 

However I tried your idea to check if the predict_proba(X), for all those which have no label predicted. 
They have the probabilities for all the labels, so the classifier is giving a probability to each label for a sample, but not predicting anything in the end.

Comment: The dataset is a collection of text documents with the features being the BOW and there are multiple classes that these are labelled with.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know, is there any difference you see in the values from one `predict_proba` with `predict` equals to `None` & the values from `predict_proba` of one sample that actually gives you a `predict`? It's hard to guess for me, but maybe you have equal values for every proba and therefore it returns a `None`? (just guessing here). In the worst case scenario you could use the method `predict_proba` and return the label (or labels if there is a tie) with the highest probability... but I know this does not explain your issue :-S

Comment: You could also try to see if another estimator also gives you `Nones`, instead of using `LogisticRegression` you could try for example a support vector machine `svm.LinearSVC()` and see how it behaves

Comment: Can you please tell me how can we calculate f scores, precision and recall for such sort of problems? am looking for the answer from couple of days here i posted a question, please take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620578/how-to-calculate-f1-measure-in-multi-label-classification

Comment: Try `Y = mlb.fit_transform([[1, 2], [1,2], [1,2],[4],[]]) ` to handle singlton and empty label sets better.