# How to Calculate F1 measure in multi-label classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, units-of-measurement, multilabel-classification

I am working on sentence category detection Problem. Where each sentence can belong to multiple categories for Example:

```
"It has great sushi and even better service."
True Label:  [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
Pred Label:  [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
Correct Prediction!
Output:  ['FOOD#QUALITY' 'SERVICE#GENERAL']
```

I have implemented a classifier that can predict multiple categories. I have total 587 sentences that belongs to multiple categories. I have calculated the accuracy scores in two ways:

> If all labels of an example predicted or not?

**code:**

```
print "<------------ZERO one ERROR------------>" 
print "Total Examples:",(truePred+falsePred) ,"True Pred:",truePred, "False Pred:", falsePred, "Accuracy:", truePred/(truePred+falsePred)
```

**Output:**

```
<------------ZERO one ERROR------------>
Total Examples: 587 True Pred: 353 False Pred: 234 Accuracy: 0.60136286201
```

> How many labels are correctly predicted for all examples?

**code:**

```
print "\n<------------Correct and inccorrect predictions------------>"
print "Total Labels:",len(total[0]),"Predicted Labels:", corrPred, "Accuracy:", corrPred/len(total[0])
```

**Output:**

```
<------------Correct and inccorrect predictions------------> 
Total Labels: 743 Predicted Labels: 522 Accuracy: 0.702557200538
```

**Problem:**
These are all the accuracy scores calculated by comparing predicted scores with ground truth labels. But i want to calculate F1 score (using micro averaging), precision and recall as well. I have ground truth labels and i need to match my predictions with those ground truth labels. But, i don't know how do i tackle such type of multi-label classification problem. 
Can i use scikit-learn or any other libraries in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made matrix of predicted labels `predictedlabel` and i already had correct categories to compare my results in `y_test`. So, i tried the following code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

print "Classification report: \n", (classification_report(y_test, predictedlabel))
print "F1 micro averaging:",(f1_score(y_test, predictedlabel, average='micro'))
print "ROC: ",(roc_auc_score(y_test, predictedlabel))
```

**and i got the following results:**

```
        precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.74      0.93      0.82        57
      1       0.00      0.00      0.00         3
      2       0.57      0.38      0.46        21
      3       0.75      0.75      0.75        12
      4       0.44      0.68      0.54        22
      5       0.81      0.93      0.87       226
      6       0.57      0.54      0.55        48
      7       0.71      0.38      0.50        13
      8       0.70      0.72      0.71       142
      9       0.33      0.33      0.33        33
     10       0.42      0.52      0.47        21
     11       0.80      0.91      0.85       145

     av/total 0.71      0.78      0.74       743

 F1 micro averaging: 0.746153846154
 ROC:  0.77407943841
```

So, i am calculating my results in this way!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#classification-metrics) already available with sklearn and understand them. They are not available for multiclass multilabel classification so you can write your own or map your categories to labels.

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.] => 0
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] => 1
...
```

You have to understand what this solution implies : if an example have 4 classes and if you have **3 out of the 4** correctly predicted, using an accuracy_score will be the **same** as a prediction of **0 out of 4** correctly predicted.

It is an error.

Here an example

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
>>> y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 3]
>>> y_true = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
0.5
```

Comment: Okay can you please tell me that, if I have a true label [0,1,0,1] and predicted label [0,1,1,0]. Then what will be the precision and recall for this single example? Or what will be the TN, TP, FN and FP.

Comment: If you do as I suggest before then your true label will be 0 and your prediction will be 1. So your precision and recall will be 0. Or you can be more subtile and compute independently for each class the precision and recall and after that average them.

Comment: So, for any example x true label [0,1,0,1] and predicted label [0,1,1,0] we cannot calculate FP, TP, TN and TP by just looking position of 1's and 0's?

Comment: Please verify my answer!!! i tried it in the following way!!! please see the answer :) thanks alot bro

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at `MultiLabelBinarizer` in case your predictions or your ground truth labels, for a multilabel scenario, do not have a constant width. This essentially converts them to a fixed length array of zeros and ones:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

y_true = [(12, 2, 4, 5),
          (5, 2),
          (12,)
         ]

y_pred = [(4, 5),
          (5, 2),
          (5, 4)
         ]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

y_true_binarized = mlb.fit_transform(y_true)
y_pred_binarized = mlb.transform(y_pred)

print(classification_report(y_true_binarized, y_pred_binarized, 
                            target_names=[str(cls) for cls in mlb.classes_]))
```